# Unable to access item in multidimensional associative array in php

Tags: php

I have the following array and I am trying to get the value of the `DEMO` key based on user input of either `IP` or `ON`.

```
$MENU_CONFIGS = array(
    "ACCEPTED" => array(
        array(
            "STATUS" => "ACTIVE",
            "LBL" => "EDIT",
            "DEMO" => array(
                "IP" => "Handout", 
                "ON" => "Video"
            ),
            "BTN_ACTION" => "Save",
            "BTN_ID" => "btnUpdatePresentation",
            "BTN_CSS_CLASS" => "doUserAction btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2",
            "JS_ACTION" => "UPDATE",
            "UPLOAD_SCRIPT" => "",
            "ICON" => "<span class='far fa-check-circle' style='color:#ffffff'></span>"
        )
    )
)
```

When I try to print `$MENU_CONFIGS['ACCEPTED']['DEMO']['IP']` I am not getting "Handout" as expected, what is wrong with the way I am trying?

Comment: `$MENU_CONFIGS['ACCEPTED']` is an indexed array with one item, so you need to reference the first item (zeroth index) with `$MENU_CONFIGS['ACCEPTED'][0]['DEMO']['IP']`. If you do `print_r($MENU_CONFIGS);` it will be easier to see the structure.

Answer (score 0):

PHP arrays should match the logic of key => value criteria. Whenever a key is omited, PHP sets an numeric index to that key.

your array looks like this:

$MENU_CONFIGS = array("ACCEPTED" => array(array("Status" => "ACTIVE", ...)))

try this code:

```
$MENU_CONFIGS = array(
    "ACCEPTED" => array(
        
            "STATUS" => "ACTIVE",
            "LBL" => "EDIT",
            "DEMO" => array(
                "IP" => "Handout", 
                "ON" => "Video"
            ),
            "BTN_ACTION" => "Save",
            "BTN_ID" => "btnUpdatePresentation",
            "BTN_CSS_CLASS" => "doUserAction btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2",
            "JS_ACTION" => "UPDATE",
            "UPLOAD_SCRIPT" => "",
            "ICON" => "<span class='far fa-check-circle' style='color:#ffffff'></span>"
        
    )
);
```

This will fix your issue.